# What is "adapter name"?

Tags: winapi, network-programming

WinAPI's `GetAdaptersInfo()` fills structure `AdapterInfo` which has field called `AdapterName`. What does this field mean? What's the point in it? In my case it holds string `"{C01E7744-531D-401F-8EA6-D76D3AF35555}"` (including curly braces).

P.S.: beside `AdapterName` there is pretty clear (for me) field called `Description` with value (in my case):

> "Realtek RTL8102E/RTL8103E Family PCI-E Fast Ethernet NIC - VirtualBox Host Interface Networking Driver Miniport"

what makes me even more confused with `AdapterName`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's just a GUID that windows assigns to the adapter, probably as a unique identifier that you can use in some other API call to reference that adapter specifically.  For example GetAdapterIndex.

Most IP helper functions seem to take an adapter index, but if you had an app that manipulated network adapters, you probably wouldn't want to store the index of a specific adapter in your app as that could change when adapters are added or removed.  So you would store the name of the adapter, then use GetAdapterIndex to get the index for it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Its formatted like so

```
GetAdapterIndex(L"\\device\\tcpip_{FD2046B5-1DA0-40A2-9F28-DE4D6F0EBE22}", &index);
```

I have no idea where this is actually documented officially but found it sourced here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/qemu/+/refs/heads/master/qga/commands-win32.c

Answer (score 0):

`Description` is the user-friendly name associated with `AdapterName`.

**Sources:**

http://www.delphigroups.info/2/8/215347.html

Comment: So, "AdapterName" is absolutely the same as "Description"? And, then, is it guaranteed that each "Description" corresponds to one (and only one) "AdapterName"?

Comment: I would assume so. I agree with Eric Petroelje that its probably just a GUID.

Comment: @Slav - I think the AdapterName should be unique, but the description isn't necessarily unique.  You could very possibly have two adapters with the same description, especially if they were the same type (like in a VirtualBox), but they should have different names.  Would be easy enough to test with a VM.